# How to implement a class constant that is different for each subclass?

Tags: moose

In my class hierarchy, I need a common attribute where each subclass needs to provide a different value that is constant for all objects of that class. (This attribute serves as a key to an existing hierarchy that I'm mirroring -- not the best OO design, but I need to preserve this link.)

One way to implement this is with attributes, like this:

```js
package TypeBase;

use Moose::Role;

has type => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => enum([qw(A B)]),
    builder => '_type',
    init_arg => nil,
    required => 1,
);

1;

#####

package TypeA;

use Moose;
with 'TypeBase';

sub _type { 'A' };

1;

#####

package TypeB;

use Moose;
with 'TypeBase';

sub _type { 'B' };

1;
```

Is there a better way to do this? I could just have `requires 'type'` in the base class, which each concrete class would have to provide, except that this loses me the type constraint that I had with the attribute route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is equivalent to yours in terms of the external interface. The main difference is the use of `constant` to better reflect what you are doing. (Note that TYPE can still be called like a method.) Because if is using `requires` it should also give you a compile-time rather than runtime error if you haven't implemented TYPE in one of your classes.

```
package TypeBase;
use Moose::Role;
requires 'TYPE';

package TypeA;
use Moose;
with 'TypeBase';
use constant TYPE => 'A';

package TypeB;
use Moose;
with 'TypeBase';
use constant TYPE => 'B';
```

Comment: I like your `use constant` approach. Restricting the set of values with attribute and `enum` gave a small amount of safety, but not in any meaningful way.